# AWS RDS limit user access to database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I'm very new to using RDS and have been searching online but can't seem to find anything that will allow me to limit a users access to only a single database on an RDS instance. I want to have two accounts, each linked to their own database within an rds instance.

Right now my first user has this as their policy (RDSFullAccess):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "rds:*",
            "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "sns:ListSubscriptions",
            "sns:ListTopics",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:GetLogEvents"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Action": "pi:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:pi:*:*:metrics/rds/*"
    }
]
```

}

What can I add to this so this user is only allowed access to a single database?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Is it one that supports IAM authentication of database connections?

Comment: @MarkB Using MySQL Community Edition

Comment: Does the user simply need to be able to connect to the database to run SQL commands? Or do they also need to be able to manage the RDS server itself, including things like taking snapshots, restoring to a previous snapshot, etc.?

Comment: @MarkB I have an account that I use to manage everything on the web side. I just want two accounts that are able to connect to the database that I choose for each.

Comment: I wouldn't use IAM authentication for that at all then. I would connect to the MySQL instance and create new MySQL users that only have the appropriate access you want them to have.

Comment: @MarkB Are there any permissions that I need in order to create a user? I'm trying using Sequel Pro and am getting an access denied error.

Comment: You need to be logged in as the admin user. That's the user ID you specified when you created the RDS instance.

Comment: @MarkB I am logged in as the admin user, is there a way to change this or add one?

Comment: A way to change what? Or add another what? You want to change the admin user now or add another admin? How is that relevant to your original question? You are asking very basic MySQL administration questions here. I suggest reading the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm logged in as the admin user for the RDS Instance but getting access denied.

Comment: What specific command are you trying to run that is giving access denied?

Comment: @JoeScotto RDS/MySQL db/table/column permissions are not controlled through IAM.  Only the ability to connect is (and then, only when using IAM auth).  The permissions for the user once logged in are all controlled inside MySQL with `GRANT` statements, in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to configure the user accounts on the actual MySQL side of things.